# How to eager load an association from a eager graph association using Sequel Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, sequel, eager

I have the following models in my application:

```
class Order < Sequel::Model
    many_to_one(:client, class: 'Client', key: :client_id)
end

class Client < Sequel::Model
    one_to_many(:images, class: 'Image', key: :client_id, eager: :file)
end

class Image < Sequel::Model
    many_to_one(:file, class: 'File', key: :file_id, eager: :namespace)
end

class File < Sequel::Model
    many_to_one(:namespace, class: 'Namespace', key: :namespace_id)
end

class Namespace < Sequel::Model
end
```

I can fetch all `Orders` for all `Clients` with `account_id=1` using eager_graph (eager_graph because the search column is in the `client` table):

```
orders = Order.eager_graph(:client).where(account_id: 1)
```

What is the best strategy to eager load all this entities?
If I change it to `.eager_graph(client: :images)` the result will be a big query with a lot of joins.

Is it possible to have a separate query for every nested associations, like it was used only the `.eager` method?

I trying to fine tune this because of performance issues.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequel doesn't currently support mixing eager and eager_graph in that way. You could do:

```
Order.eager(:client=>{proc{|ds| ds.where(:account_id=>1)}=>:images}).all.
  select{|order| order.client}
```

But that may not be very efficient if most orders do not have that client.  You may be better off doing:

```
clients = Client.where(:account_id=>1).eager(:orders, :images)
clients.flat_map(&:orders)
```

Comment: This worked, the number of queries was what i expected but i cannot paginate the orders using limit/offset.

The eager is loading all orders for all clients and i think limiting on the ruby side is not efficient.
Thanks for the help anyway, i appreciate your work

Comment: Sequel's master branch now supports what you want via the eager_graph_eager plugin: https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/commit/7a19a1617847ec9be12bac5104cf01bda102ff78